# Reduce a set of vectors of $\mathbb{R}^3$ to a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

$V_1 =(1,0,0); V_2=(0,1,-1); V_3= (0,4,-3); V_4=(0,2,0)$ reduce this to obtain a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ .        I obtained a matrix as follows and then obtained its row echelon form, but then i cannot understand how I obtain basis from that matrix. 
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 &0 &0 &0\\ 0 &1 &4& 2\\ 0 &-1 & -3& 0\end{bmatrix}$$ and its row echelon form is $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 &  0\\ 0 &1 &4 & 2\\ 0 & 0& 1 &2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the vectors $v_1,\dotsc,v_4$ into the columns of a matrix
$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 4 & 2 \\
0 & -1 & -3 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
The columns of $A$ corresponding to pivots in $\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref(A)$ form a basis of $\Bbb R^3$. In our case, 
$$
\rref(A)=\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -6 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2
\end{array}\right]
$$
Hence $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is a basis of $\Bbb R^3$.

Answer (score 1):

By inspection:

$\vec e_1 = V_1$, and

$\vec e_2 = (1/2) V_4$;

$\vec e_3 = V_3 - 4V_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are linearly independent, and we know that $\mathbb{R}$ has the dimension 3, the vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3$ forms a basis for $\mathbb{R}$.